# Python tkinter check button printing PY_VAR0

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter

So this is the code, which draws heavily from this question:

[How do I create multiple checkboxes from a list in a for loop in python tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8536518/how-do-i-create-multiple-checkboxes-from-a-list-in-a-for-loop-in-python-tkinter).

```
from tkinter import * 

root = Tk()

enable = {'jack': 0, 'john': 1} 

def actright(x):
    print(enable.get(x))

for machine in enable:
    enable[machine] = Variable()
    l = Checkbutton(root, text=machine, variable=enable[machine], 
                    command=  actright(machine))
    l.pack(anchor = W)

root.mainloop()
```

I expected the output to be:

```
0
1
```

Instead the output is:

```
PY_VAR0
PY_VAR1
```

How can I get these values without the "PY_VAR" preceding the number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the  `enable[machine] = Variable()`

```
for machine in enable:
    l = Checkbutton(root, text=machine, variable=enable[machine],
                    command=  actright(machine))
    l.pack(anchor = W)

root.mainloop()
```

You see `PY_VAR0` and `PY_VAR1` because you set the values to those with `enable[machine] = Variable()`, that overwrites the values in your dict so it makes sense that you get the output you do.

Comment: No worries, happy tkintering!