# Calling a variable from one function in another

Tags: python, function

I have a class, in which two functions are present.

I wish to access a variable created within one function from the other.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

    Message1 = None
    Keyword1 = None
    Keyword2 = None


    Message_Ent = tk.Entry(self, textvariable = Message1)
    Key1_Ent = tk.Entry(self, textvariable = Keyword1)
    Key2_Ent = tk.Entry(self, textvariable = Keyword2)


def Main_Cipher(*args):
    #Need to use these variables:
    #Message1
    #Keyword1
    #Keyword2
```

Comment: use `self.variable` within a class?

Comment: Can you give an example?  I'm not quite clear what you are asking.

Comment: Tkinter is no different than anything else in python. Without seeing code it's impossible to know what you're doing wrong. Please read http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Right now `Message1`, `Keyword1`, and `Keyword2` are [local variables](https://www.ibiblio.org/swaroopch/byteofpython/read/local-variables.html). You want to make them [instance variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instance_variable) of the class. You do this using the `self` keyword:

```
def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

    self.Message1 = None
    self.Keyword1 = None
    self.Keyword2 = None


    Message_Ent = tk.Entry(self, textvariable = self.Message1)
    Key1_Ent = tk.Entry(self, textvariable = self.Keyword1)
    Key2_Ent = tk.Entry(self, textvariable = self.Keyword2)


def Main_Cipher(*args):
    #these are now accessible here:
    print self.Message1
    print self.Keyword1
    print self.Keyword2
```

Comment: That just outputs : PY_VAR0, PY_VAR1, PY_VAR2 for the variables

Comment: So those are the values of those variables... is that not what you expect? Look here, you might be overwriting them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31126872/python-tkinter-check-button-printing-py-var0