# How to create multiple checkbox in loop using tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, checkbox, tkinter

I am New to use `Tkinter`.I want to create multiple checkbox from loop.I refer [Tkinter checkboxes created in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45313992/tkinter-checkboxes-created-in-loop) but i don't understand it.
I want to display all files as a checkbox located in a directory.

Help me and tell me what i need to change ?

**Code:**

```
from tkinter import filedialog,Checkbutton

import tkinter,os

window = tkinter.Tk()

def browse():

    filez = filedialog.askdirectory(parent=window,title='Choose a file')#I choose a directory

    ent1.insert(20,filez)#insert the path of directory to text box
    dirs = os.listdir(filez)#gives all files of direcory
    for file in dirs:
       print(file)#Getting all files
       var = tkinter.IntVar()
       c = tkinter.Checkbutton(window,text=file,variable=var)#Create files to checkox
       c.place(x=0,y=100)



window.title("First Gui")

window.geometry("400x400")
window.wm_iconbitmap("path of icon")

lbl = tkinter.Label(window,text="path")

lbl.place(x=0,y=60)

ent1 = tkinter.Entry(window)

ent1.place(x=80,y=60)

btn1 = tkinter.Button(window,text="Set Path",command=browse)

btn1.place(x=210,y=57)


window.mainloop()
```

After click on button set path i want to to display all files of directory as a checkbox using browse function

Comment: you put all checkboxes in one place `c.place(x=0,y=100)` so you can't see them. Better use `pack()` or `grid()` - they are more elastick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see three problems

1. you use `c.place(x=0,y=100)` for all `Checkbuttons` so you can see only last one - other are hidden behind last one.
2. every `Checkbutton` need own `IntVar` which you can keep on list or in dictionary.
3. when you select new path then you have to remove previous `Checkbuttons` so you have to remember them on list or in dictionary.

Example shows how you could use `pack()` instead of `place()` to easily put all `Checkbuttons`. It also show how to uses dictionary to keep `IntVars` and check which was selected, and how to use list to keep `Checkbuttons` and remove them later from window.

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.filedialog
import os

# --- functions ---

def browse():

    filez = tkinter.filedialog.askdirectory(parent=window, title='Choose a file')

    ent1.insert(20, filez)

    dirs = os.listdir(filez)

    # remove previous IntVars
    intvar_dict.clear()

    # remove previous Checkboxes
    for cb in checkbutton_list:
        cb.destroy()
    checkbutton_list.clear() 

    for filename in dirs:
        # create IntVar for filename and keep in dictionary
        intvar_dict[filename] = tkinter.IntVar()

        # create Checkbutton for filename and keep on list
        c = tkinter.Checkbutton(window, text=filename, variable=intvar_dict[filename])
        c.pack()
        checkbutton_list.append(c)

def test():
    for key, value in intvar_dict.items():
        if value.get() > 0:
            print('selected:', key)

# --- main ---

# to keep all IntVars for all filenames
intvar_dict = {}
 # to keep all Checkbuttons for all filenames
checkbutton_list = []

window = tkinter.Tk()

lbl = tkinter.Label(window, text="Path")
lbl.pack()

ent1 = tkinter.Entry(window)
ent1.pack()

btn1 = tkinter.Button(window, text="Select Path", command=browse)
btn1.pack()

btn1 = tkinter.Button(window, text="Test Checkboxes", command=test)
btn1.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks . I got files but it is going down to the screen .how to add scroll bar ?

Comment: it is easy to add scrollbar to [Listbox](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm) but not to group of widgets. The only solution is to put `Checkbuttons` in `Frame`, `Frame` put on `Canvas` and you can scroll `Canvas`. You can find some examples. Yesterday was event question on SO

Comment: I put example with Scrolled Frame on GitHub [scrolled-frame.py](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/tkinter/scrolled-frame-canvas/scrolled-frame.py)