# Select and plot lists through checkbuttons (python, tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, checkbox, tkinter.checkbutton

Say I got a multidimensional list:

`my_list = [[1,2,3,4,5], [2,3,4,5,6], [3,4,5,6,7]]`

Now  I want to create a GUI with Tkinter where one could check boxes to select which of these sub-lists should be plotted in a histogram. So for this example I imagine three checkboxes (labeled 0, 1, 2) and a `Button` "Show Histograms". Say I check boxes labeled 1 and 2 and press the "Show Histograms" Button, it should show the histograms of `my_list[0]`and `my_list[1]`(preferably as subplots on one canvas).
What would be the approach?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how-do-i-create-multiple-checkboxes-from-a-list-in-a-for-loop-in-python-tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8536518)

Comment: not really somehow, sorry... I've wrote a code which does what I want but it is really unautomatic and I don't know how to do it better. I'll show it beneath.

Answer (score 2):

> **OOP Example**:

Defines a `class SubplotCheckbutton ...`, inheriting from `tk.Checkbutton`.
Extends the `tk.Checkbutton` widget with:

- Named argument `subplot=`
- The required `tk.Variable`, here `tk.IntVar`
- A class method `checked()` which returns `True/False` according the checked state.

---

**Reference**:

- [Correctly extend a tkinter widget using inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60322108/7414759)
- [The Tkinter Checkbutton Widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/checkbutton.htm)

---

1. ***What do the arguments `parent`and `**kwargs` in the init method mean?***
   Every `Tkinter` widget needs a `parent`. Therefore the first argument of all `Tkinter`widgets class objects take the `parent` argument. A parent in Tkinter specifies in which widget your widget, here `Checkbutton`, are layouted.

   - `class App(tk.Tk):` => `self`
   - `SubplotCheckbutton(self, ...`
   - `def __init__(..., parent, ...`
   - `super().__init__(parent, ...` => *`tk.Checkbutton(parent)`*

---

`**kwargs` are shorted from **known word arguments** and is of type `dict`.
Here: `text=str(i)` and `subplot=subplot`

2. will be continued ...

---

```
import tkinter as tk


class SubplotCheckbutton(tk.Checkbutton):
    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        # Pop the 'subplot=' argument and save to class member
        self.subplot = kwargs.pop('subplot')

        # Extend this class with the required tk.Variable
        self.variable = tk.IntVar()

        # __init__ the inherited (tk.Checkbutton) class object
        # Pass the argument variable= and all other passed arguments in kwargs
        super().__init__(parent, variable=self.variable, **kwargs)

    # Extend this object with a checked() method
    def checked(self):
        # Get the value from the tk.Variable and return True/False
        return self.variable.get() == 1
```

> **Usage**:

**Note**: No `root`, the class object `App` is the root object, therefore you have to use `self` as parent:

- `SubplotCheckbutton(self, ...`
- `Button(self, ...`

```
class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        my_list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
        self.channels = []

        for i, subplot in enumerate(my_list):
            self.channels.append(SubplotCheckbutton(self, text=str(i), subplot=subplot))
            self.channels[-1].pack()

        tk.Button(self, text="Show Histograms", command=self.show).pack()

    def show(self):
        for channel in self.channels:
            if channel.checked():
                fig, ax = plt.subplots()
                y, x, _ = ax2.hist(channel.subplot, bins = 150)
                plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    App().mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks! I do not understand everything though. 
1. What do the arguments _parent_ and _**kwargs_ in the init method mean?  In beginner tutorials I learned that you put _self_ and all class variables in the init method. What does parent mean? Does it compromise all class variables of my class I inherit from (tk.Checkbutton in this case)?
2. What does kwargs.pop() exactly do? Where is the subplot argument passed and what is beeing popped?
3. What does it mean when the super().__innit__() method has no arguments (in class App(tk.Tk))
4. In general, what would be the benefit of  OOP approach?

Comment: @Jailbone  ***Parent is then just convention?***: Yes. Are the `**kwargs` thing clear?

Comment: Not 100 percent. Let me explain how I understand the code. So the `App()` class just appends the `SubplotCheckbutton` classes to a list with corresponding `**kwargs` through enumeration of `my_list` and packs the Checkbuttons on the screen. If the channels are checked they get plotted. My missing link is how it is veryfied if the channels are checked. This happens in the `SubplotCheckbutton` class itself. As I see this class has two class variables (subplot and variable). Why is it not necessary to designate them in the `innit` method? So basically I don' understand what this class does.

Comment: ***packs the Checkbutton on the screen.***: In `Tkinter` speaking: The widget, here `SubplotCheckbutton`, are layout inside the `App` Toplevel window as you pass `self` as `parent` using *The Pack Layout Manager*.

Comment: ***My missing link is how it is veryfied if the channels are checked.***: It's done inside `def checked(...`. It is the same as yours: `if varChannels[i].get() == 1:` but Object oriented, means the Object `SubplotCheckbutton` knows the checked status. That's one benefit of OOP, **ALL** are in the same Object. Therefore it's called **Object Oriented Programming**.

Comment: ***two class variables (subplot and variable). Why is it not necessary to designate them in the innit method?*** They are in `__init__` ? ***what this class does.***: Basicly extends the `Tkinter.Checkbutton` class to aggregate all whats needed to work.

Comment: I learned it like that for example:
`class Shirt:
def __init__(self, brand, size, color):
self.brand = ....
`
So i was wondering why there is no `subplot` and `variable` in the `innit` method.

Comment: ***wondering why there is no subplot and variable***: They are passed as `**kwargs` using `subplot=...` but `variable` don't habe to be passed it is defined inside `__init__` to exetend the object to know the checked status.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't get it. So `subplot = ...` is a `**kwarg` and `variable` is already known from the parent class, i.e. `tk.Checkbutton` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216580/discussion-between-stovfl-and-jailbone).

Answer (score 0):

```
root = Tk()

my_list = [[1,2,3,4,5], [2,3,4,5,6], [3,4,5,6,7]]

var = IntVar()
var2 = IntVar()
var3 = IntVar()

def show():
    

    if var.get() == 1: 
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        y, x, _ = ax.hist(my_list[0], bins = 150)
        

    if var2.get() == 1:
        fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots()
        y, x, _ = ax2.hist(my_list[1], bins = 150)
        

    if var3.get()    def checked(self):
        return self.variable.get() == 1

 == 1:
        fig3, ax3 = plt.subplots()
        y, x, _ = ax3.hist(my_list[2], bins = 150)
    
    plt.show()





button = Button(root, text = "Show Histograms", command = show).pack()

c = Checkbutton(root, text = 'first list', variable = var).pack()
c2 = Checkbutton(root, text = 'second list', variable = var2).pack()
c3 = Checkbutton(root, text = 'third list', variable = var3).pack()


root.mainloop()
```

UPDATE: I managed to write it more compact but it does not work like that:

```
my_list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
varChannels = []
checkbuttonChannels = []

def show():
    for i in range(3):
        if varChannels[i] == 1:
            fig, ax = plt.subplots()
            y, x, _ = ax2.hist(my_list[i], bins = 150)
            plt.show()



for _ in range(3):
    varChannels.append(IntVar())
    checkbuttonChannels.append('0')

for i in range(3):
    checkbuttonChannels[i] = Checkbutton(root, text = str(i), variable = varChannels[i]).pack()

button = Button(root, text = "Show Histograms", command = show).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: ***but it does not work***: Should read: `if varChannels[i].get() == 1:`

Comment: thanks a lot! it works now. could you maybe explain in a few words how your code works? I am really new to classes stuff. So I can learn.